# Identical record fields, echo only one (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I will try the best to explain what I mean, Sorry if this has been asked before, I just don't know what I'm looking for, to find the answer?

As an example lets say I have a table called `TEST` and in this table I have identical names with different data, here is an example:

```
NAME  |  EXAMPLE    |  ID
----------------------------
ONE   |  HELLO      |  22  
ONE   |  GOODBYE    |  23  
TWO   |  GREETINGS  |  45  
TWO   |  FAREWELL   |  12  
THREE |  HEY        |  11  
THREE |  BYE        |  81
```

As you can see, in the row `NAME` - `ONE, TWO & THREE` are the same but with different data in `EXAMPLE` and `ID`. Lets day I want to show/ echo the column  `NAME`:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data-example ORDER BY id');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>

<?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Its output will be:

```
ONE
ONE
TWO
TWO
THREE
THREE
```

What I wanted to only output one of each `NAME` in this column? for example, the output should look like this:

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

What is best practise to echo a column in `php loop` that does not output identical names, in a sense recognise that there are two fields with the same name but only use one field?

**NOTE:** *I apologise, if this has been asked before, if so please direct me to the post.*

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY name`

Comment: Since you only seem to care about one field you can also use `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM data-example ORDER BY id`.  You would want an index on `name` in either case (for DISTINCT or GROUP BY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do this in php, as MySQL can do the job for you. Simply add `GROUP BY name` before your `ORDER` clause.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution, seemed very complicated in my mind. Could not find a solution anywhere!

Comment: Im glad I could help you. Please remember to accept answers if they solved your problem.

Comment: In 5 minutes, I will be allowed to click the tick.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't need the rest of the table you could change

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data-example ORDER BY id');
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT distinct name FROM data-example');
```